# Include JS file within private scope

Tags: javascript

I simply want the ability to include a JS file, but not have it evaluated in the global scope.

I have skimmed over labjs and requirejs, and although they can do 1000 other things it doesn't seem that either is able to solve this problem.

I am aware that I could wrap the code of `foo.js` such that it expects a certain context, and can act within in, but that is not what I'm looking for (having to alter the source files). Rather, I would like the source JS files to remain as any other JS file that doesn't need any sort of metadata or any resolving of the runtime execution context via code *in the included file itself*; outside of the included file, that is ok.

Some simple demonstrations for clarity:

```
/*
 * Example 1 - apply to current context
 */
function x() {  
    include('foo.js'); // provides foo()
    foo(); // ok!
}
foo(); // not ok!


/*
 * Example 2 - apply to namespace context
 */
include.apply(ns, ['foo.js']); // provides foo()
ns.foo(); // ok!
foo(); // not ok!
```

I know that this can likely be achieved using `eval()` or by creating a `new Function` with the string, but I am hoping that there is a better solution.

Comment: Caja might be worth looking at: https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/

Comment: +1 interesting question, I say go with eval. Yeah eval can be dangerous if misused, but if it gets the job done and your putting it to good use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going to close out this old question, sadly no acceptable solutions were found. Some good suggestions, but all broke the requirements that I had. I guess it may be impossible with the current featureset of the language.

Answer (score 3):

There is no *clean* way to do this without relying on the included source files to *conform to some sort of pattern* (I can think of the possibility of injecting each file into its own iframe, so they run with their own `window`, but I don't think that's ideal).

That doesn't necessarily mean that you cannot achieve decoupling of the included files (without awareness of the runtime context as you say), but the files will still need to be well-behaved.

The CommonJS Module system (which [RequireJS supports](http://requirejs.org/docs/commonjs.html)) shows one way to achieve this. By wrapping code in a function that provides an `exports` object, and assigning all (previously) global properties to this object, RequireJS can then return this object for you to assign to any object in any scope.

For example:

```
function x() {  
    var foo = require('foo.js').foo; // provides foo()
    foo(); // ok!
}
foo(); // not ok!

var ns = require('foo.js');
ns.foo(); // ok!
foo(); // not ok!
```

Yes, this requires editing the source files, but it still provides the benefits you're after.

Answer (score 3):

I do not think it's possible to do so in ways other than what you outlined yourself.

One solution is to wrap the code in a function on the server side and write an include function that loads the js file and responds with the namespace of the function. I think of a solution similar to the require function in node.js.

Wrapped code on serverside

```
require.response('foo', function(exports) {

    // Content in foo.js
    exports.a = function() { return 'A'; }
    this.b = function() { return 'B'; }
    function c() { return 'c'); }

});
```

Client side js:

```
window['require'] = (function() {

    var list = {};
    function require(name, cb) {
        if (list[name]) {
            if (list[name].ns) {
                cb(list[name].ns);
            }
            else {
                list[name].cb.push(cb);
            }
        }
        else {
            list[name] = {cb: [cb]};

            // Code to load js file

        }
    }

    require.response = function(name, func) {
        var ns = {};
        list[name].ns = ns;
        func.call(ns);
        for(var i = 0, l = list[name].cb; i < l; i++) {
            list[name].cb[i](ns);
        }
    }

    return require;

}());
```

Example usage:

```
require('foo', function(foo) {
    foo.a(); // ok
    foo.b(); // ok
    foo.c(); // error
};

foo.a(); // error
this.a(); // error
c(); // error
```

Comment: It looks like this is basically the same answer that Box9 gives, no? I know that you put your answer in at the same time, so I'm not trying to say that you copied him, but after looking at the RequireJS docs, I believe the code from node.js likely comes from the CommonJS project?

Comment: It may be right, but I'm not really the right person to answer that. Since I posted the post, I've written a little more completely implementation of the script above. There will probably be something I use in future projects. I can post it if it would be of interest?

Comment: No thank you. My current solution is basically what has already been posted -- wrapping the 'included' code within some special code. The purpose of this question was to see if this could be accomplished _without_ doing such. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

The [`clientside-require` package](https://github.com/uladkasach/clientside-module-manager) utilizes iframes to contain the scope of the loaded javascript.

After loading the script to your page:

```
<script src = "path/to/clientside-require/src/index.js"></script>
```

You can conduct the functionality you wanted as follows:

```
/*
 * Example 1 - apply to current context
 */
require("foo.js")
  .then((foo)=>{
     foo(); // ok
  })
foo(); // not ok


/*
 * Example 2 - apply to namespace context
 */
var promise_foo_attached = require("foo.js")
  .then((foo)=>{
    window.ns.foo = foo; // provides foo to ns
  })

// then, as long as promise_foo_attached has resolved:
ns.foo(); // ok!
foo(); // not ok!
```

Note, because browsers do not allow synchronous loading of resources (due to poor user experience) any attempt at loading an external script with javascript will necessarily be asynchronous (and thus use promises).

Unless browsers enable synchronous loading, this format will be the closest to what we are looking for.

---

As an added bonus, the `require()` functionality that that script loads can be used to load `html`, `css`, `json`, and even `node_modules` (as long as the modules are capable of working with `require()` as a promise).